# MySql Workbench csv Import Datetime DATATYPE as TEXT

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime, type-conversion

Trying to import data from csv to Mysql database using mysql Workbench `Table Data Import Wizard`. The csv contains a dattime field in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss (eg. 28/01/2017 10:55:00 PM).
If I go by default settings, workbench considers the datetime as 'TEXT' datatype and imports data successfully. However, If I change the datatype to 'DATETIME', the import completes with '0 records imported'.

Answer (score 2):

The datetime format for mysql database is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS...
Check out the documentation [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIyOHXvJvSAhWGtY8KHcsSB8MQFggdMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Fen%2Fdatetime.html&usg=AFQjCNGc5DXXoRcxKpV46ARaMvjZVVL4ZA&sig2=kBy0FVFl_4feRkkfiPyoeg).
Hope this helps.....

Answer (score 0):

Dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` are not standard, hence MySQL is treating it as text.  And forcing it to load such data as datetime is also wrong.

This problem is well suited to `LOAD DATA` along with the `STR_TO_DATE()` function to convert the date strings into proper dates:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'input.csv'
INTO TABLE t1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(column1, @var1, column3, ...)
SET column2 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

The above `LOAD DATA` would be appropriate if the second column in your CSV file contained the date data.  If not, then just rearrange it so that the correct column gets parsed.